# Change Woocommerce endpoint url

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I need help with a little problem. I've installed the woocommerce subscription plugin to give my customers the option to subscribe something. Because it looks and sounds better I've changed all strings form "subscriptions" to "flatrates" but the url is the same.

Where can I change the endpoint url name? 
Like from

`/my_account/subscriptions`

to

`/my_account/my-flatrates`

for example?

Comment: you have that page??/my_account/my-flatrates

Comment: As a file? No the name of the file is subscriptions.php

Comment: no i have to ask that do you want redirection??

Comment: No, I want to change the url name for this site from `https://mywebsite.de/de/my_account/subscriptions/` to `https://mywebsite/de/my_account/my-flatrates/` but the content should be the same.

Comment: may be you are looking at this kind of official dev doc: https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/tabbed-my-account-pages-in-2-6/ or this link to: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/2.6-Tabbed-My-Account-page

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks for your answer. I've tried to change the endpoint url but its so hard. After couple of hours I'm at the beginning again becuase I've destroyed a lot and the site was no longer available :/

Comment: @ItsOdi1 Yes this is a not really easy level … But this docs and some recent answers (as it's woocommerce version +2.6) on stackOverFlow should put you on the right way. Once you will get this working, you will be very satisfied to do it by your self…